# Acrobat Failed to Load core DLL without any rootkits

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I am having an issue with an enduser getting this error.

After a brief Google search, I found the article [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/reader-core-dll-error.html).  When I launch Adobe Acrobat X I recieve the following error:

> Acrobat Failed to Load core DLL.

I ran the rootkit removal tool, a scan with SEP, a scan with MalwareBytes, I did the clean uninstall/reboot/reinstall from the tool provided, and to no avail, it still provides me with the same error.

Comment: Provide the log file, the error, or something that helps you figure out the cause of your problem. Have you tried to reinstall Acrobat?

Comment: As previously mentioned, I provided the error, already stated I uninstalled/reinstalled and as an IT professional I have no idea how else to proceed.  Below you will find that there are no errors logged in the event viewer.  After following reading what @Dave-Rook mentioned, I am still stuck in the same point.

Comment: If you state this in your question its not clear.  Have you tried to run the `Acrobat Cleaner Tool` and after you reboot attempt to install and run `Acrobat XI`?

Comment: Yes I did (I guess I wasn't clear with that too because I mentioned it in the original question - also in the followup to Dave Rook).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove Acrobat, then run the removal tool, then re-install Acrobat.

If that doesn't work, then a work around includes (and you didn't state what OS, so this is for Windows since the link in your post is for a Windows fix)

> Here is a work around until I figure out the cause.  Copy all the FILES, not folders, from C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader x.x\reader to C:\

[Source](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5201386)

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is Windows 7 x64, in a office environment (Windows 2003 AD domain)

Comment: Okay, I copied the files to C root, and I get the same error.  When I first started Adobe Reader, I got an error about Protected Mode, but I chose Always Open with Protected Mode disabled, but I get the same error about core nonetheless.  I also found when I start Windows and after logging in, I got an error about reader_sl.exe was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).  There were no logs in the event viewer logged pertaining to anything as to what is currently going on.

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub - Despite what everything is saying your computer's system image is corrupted ( more then likely by malware that was already removed at some point)

Comment: I literally think ramhounds comment is perfect .. sorry,  bite the bullet and reformat.

Comment: I had just been made aware that a second enduser in the origanisation is having the same issue.  Also Windows 7 x64.  I recently pushed out the msi for Acro Reader XI but there are 100+ computers in my AD!

Comment: @Ramhound - I would had thought that too, but now a second enduser is complaining of the same thing - both with the Protected Mode nonsense.  I don't know if it is an issue with Win 7 x64 (My machine is x86) and 100+ endusers all received the push for Reader XI.  I used the config tool to generate the mst file, so unless its a 64-bit issue, I don't think it is corruption when more than one computer is exhibiting the same thing.  I can try to downgrade them to Acrobat X, or manually install rather than use active directory.  Maybe that will give me more insight.

Comment: This issue needs to be brought up with adobe. I suggest you get in touch direct.

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub - You are installing 64-bit installation of Acrobat ( I assume there is one ) on those machines that are running 64-bit operating systems correct?  Have you ran "sfc /scannow" on the trouble machines?

Comment: @ramhound No, I am using the regular distributable version of Acrobat Reader.  I did post this originally in the Adobe forums and got no response, I am not sure whom to contact at Adobe.  I am thinking I may downgrade those folks, at least as an experiment to see if it makes any difference.  But, no I did not think of running sfc, I will give that a shot too.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I just uninstalled Reader XI - I had to use the cleaner tool, since X and XI wouldn't allow me to install it, so I did the full XI from the adobe site, not the msi I am pushing, and same error, so I uninstalled again, cleaner tool, then X and now it works fine.  Not too sure.  I guess I have to contact Adobe then because its only an issue so far on Windows 7 x64 folks.

Comment: @JonathanWeinraub, is this not what my post suggested though? Uninstall, run the cleaner, then re-install? Or was it not that simple?

Comment: @DaveRook, it is what I first did, but it did not work with Adobe Reader XI.  I had to downgrade to Adobe Reader X.  I was hoping my endusers can use the latest version, since it gets pushed automatically via group policy.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by installing the 32-bit (x86) [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999).

I figured this out by running [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on AcroRd32.dll. There were several errors indicating that a 32-bit DLL was trying to load the 64-bit MSVC 2010 runtime DLLs. Installing the x86 redistributable package fixed the issue.